# Command prompt netsat malware detection

Tags: malware, http, netstat

I suspect I have malware in my laptop. Can someone explain what is happening in that log? I'm using public WiFi.

[image: Can someone explain whats happening?]

[image]

Comment: Don't post (only) screenshots, they are not searchable. Add text.

Answer (score 2):

Running netstat -b shows fields for current connections with info on:

**Protocol:** TCP or UDP, TCP is web traffic

**Local Address:** If it's 127.0.0.1, it's on your loopback interface (meaning how your computer talks to itself).  In this case, it looks like DESKTOP-D476NPG is your computer's name.  From the looks of it here, firefox plugins are using this and it appears legitimate.

When it's 10.100.170.103, it's your normal network interface.  The 10.x address indicates you have a local area network using the 10.x.x.x address space of RFC1918, and likely is running a DHCP server starting with an address of .100.  This indicates your computer is likely the third device on the network to connect to ethernet/wifi.

**Foreign address**: the remote server you're connecting to.  In this case, a lot of amazon servers, MSN, and other typical web traffic.

There is one connection going from 10.100.170.103 to 192.168.18.240, which indicates that you're likely on a LAN or a VPN connection with another local RFC1918 subnet.  This could also be the result of a misconfigured "double-NATing" setup where a local router has one IP range, and a wireless router has another.  In either case, the data shows this is from the Windows 10 update service attempting to serve peer-to-peer updates, as it's configured by default.

**State**:  Shows if the connection is established (meaning connected), or TIME_WAIT meaning has been finished.  SYN_RECEIVED means that the remote host has sent a TCP SYNchronize requesting a connection, but has not sent back the SYN-ACK acknowledging your host's ACKnowledgement of the connection request.

**Consider other options**

netstat -b is one basic way to see what connections your computer may be making, but is hard to read and depending on the interval may miss items.  A packet sniffer like WireShark, or better yet one attached to another network device like Snort or an intrusion detection system would be more effective.  Several AntiVirus vendors also sell a host-based intrusion detection system (HIDS) which constantly analyzes network traffic to determine if any is suspicious.